# MISRA-C 2012 Rule16.7について

Tags: c

Rule16.7 switch文の制御式は、実質的なブール型を持ってはいけない

とありますが、制御式に定数を使用することは、「実質的なブール型」に該当するでしょうか。

例:

```
#define NUM 20
switch(NUM)
{
case 10:
 break;
case 20:
 break;
default:
 break
}
```

Comment: タイトルの2011ですが、2012の誤記でしょうか？
https://www.misra.org.uk/Activities/MISRAC/tabid/160/Default.aspx

Comment: 2012ですね。修正します。

Answer (score 4):

この場合の「ブール型」は `true` / `false` 類似の２値のことと考えてよくて

```
switch (something) {
case some_true:
   true_job();
   break;
default:
   false_job();
   break;
}
```

はダメよ、これなら `if` にすべきであると MISRA は主張しています。

制御式に３値以上あるなら `switch` 内で使う値が１値であっても該当しないと考えています。例えば組み込み機器の通信仕様として「データ取得」「データ設定」「返信」など３種類以上のコマンドタイプがあるとして、とあるコマンドは（今のところ）「取得」しか受け付けないなら

```
enum message_type { mt_query, mt_change, mt_reply };
/* 通信電文上、このコマンドは今のところ query しか対応しない */
switch (message_type()) {
case mt_query:
    return build_query_result();
default:
    return build_negative_acknowledge();
}
```

は OK でしょう。このコードに対して MISRA が警告出しても「今後、コマンドの仕様を拡張することがありうる」という理由でオイラは逸脱を選択します。

提示例は理解しがたいです（そのようなコードを本当に書いているなら MISRA 以前にソースコードレビューで拒絶対象） `NUM` が定数でなくて変数であって、値 `10` が `true` 相当、値 `20` が `false` 相当、それ以外の値は通常ならありえなくて、もし渡されてくるなら `assert` 相当（要するにバグなりハードウエア上の RAM 化け）なら 16.7 に該当します。